# cat on Mac OS X never exits

Tags: macos, osx-snow-leopard, unix, cat

I'm a bit of a UNIX noob, but I'm trying to run the cat command to make a simple text file and it works great, however cat is never exited after making the file. For instance, I type cat > ~/mytextfile.txt and hit enter, the file is created but my cursor remains on a blank line.

Comment: `cat` is most often used for dumping the contents of one file into another, ex. `cat file1 > file2` or feeding a file to a pipe, ex. `cat file | somecommand`. If you simply want to create an empty file, use the command `touch`. If you wish to create a new file with a few simple words, or append a few lines to an existing file, `echo` is a common solution.

Comment: @Darth - You should write your comment as an answer instead.

Comment: "feeding a file to a pipe, ex. cat file | somecommand"
'cat'ting in this context, though commonly done, is completely useless.
'somecommand <file' is equivalent and runs one less process.  The only way it might make sense would be to concatenate several files into a single input stream for 'somecommand'

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You're telling `cat` to send nothing to a file. Use `touch` (as mentioned) instead.

Answer (score 10):

You have to send an `EOF (^D)` character on the standard input to tell `cat` to stop.

Comment: I see, how can I get ^D? Or what is the shortcut or whatever?

Comment: It is the key combination `ctrl + d`.

Comment: Worth noting that lots of *nix command line apps (all the ones that read input from stdin) work the same way.

Answer (score 3):

In my MAC I need to send EOF (^D) twice.

Example:

```
cat > /tmp/mypassword
RandomLettersAndNumbers123
```

Then press `FN + Control + D` twice.